# Update row in sqlite isn`t updating

Tags: ios, iphone, sqlite, sql-update

I am trying to update just one cell in row but I can`t get it work. Method for updating:

```
- (void) UpdateQuestionShownParameter:(int)QuestionId :(BOOL)QuestionShown{
    @try {
        NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        NSString *dbPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath ]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Milionar.sqlite"];
        const char *sql = "UPDATE Questions set Show = ? WHERE id = ?";


        BOOL success = [fileMgr fileExistsAtPath:dbPath];
        if(!success)
        {
            NSLog(@"Cannot locate database file '%@'.", dbPath);
        }
        if(sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &db) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            sqlite3_stmt *sqlStatement;
            if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, -1, &sqlStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
            {
                NSInteger shownInteger = (QuestionShown ? 1 : 0);

                sqlite3_bind_int(sqlStatement, 1, shownInteger);
                sqlite3_bind_int(sqlStatement, 2, QuestionId);

                if (sqlite3_step(sqlStatement) != SQLITE_DONE)
                {
                    NSLog(@"Error while updating. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
                }
                sqlite3_finalize(sqlStatement);

            }
            else
            {
                NSLog(@"Problem with prepare statement");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"An error has occured while opening database.");
        }

        sqlite3_close(db);

    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"An exception occured: %@", [exception reason]);
    }
}
```

Trying in ViewDidLoad:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    ListOfQuestions *listQuestions =[[ListOfQuestions alloc] init];
    self.Questions = [listQuestions getQuestions];
    Question *generatedQuestion = (Question *) [self.Questions objectAtIndex:0];
    [listQuestions UpdateQuestionShownParameter:generatedQuestion.id :TRUE];
    [self.Description setText:(generatedQuestion.Description)];

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

Everytime when I tried to run app I get 0 in Shown column. But I don`t have any errors. So am I doing something wrong or everytime when I tried to run app in emulator I get recreate database from project database?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are opening the database in the bundle, which is read-only. You should be copying the database from bundle to Documents folder if the database doesn't already exist in Documents folder:

```
NSString *filename         = @"Milionar.sqlite";
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSString *bundlePath       = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath ]stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];
NSString *documentsFolder  = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0];
NSString *documentsPath    = [documentsFolder stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];

if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:documentsPath]) {
    NSError *error = nil;
    BOOL success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:bundlePath toPath:documentsPath error:&error];
    NSAssert(success, @"Unable to copy database: %@", error);
}

if (sqlite3_open([documentsPath UTF8String], &db) != SQLITE_OK) {
    NSLog(@"Open failed");
} else {
    // ...
}
```

For more information about where documents belong, see the [File System Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html).

---

By the way, if you're looking for the Documents folder for your simulator, that's located in `~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator` (in Xcode 6, this is now `~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices`). If you don't see the "Library" folder, you can unhide it by typing the following command into your Terminal command line interface:

```
chflags nohidden ~/Library
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for and with link to article and with great tip. Thanks++